# c language, is there any way how to send a command into popen() opened shell

Tags: c, linux, input, sh, popen

I’d like to send commands into opened popen() function in C
Tried to use fputs(), but it is not working. Do you know any other ways? For example, FILE *pw = popen(“sudo apt-get …”, “w”) wants user to input password from keyboard, how to input it from string char *sudopass = “password”.
Thanks a lot!

I wanna make authomatical input from string instead of keyboard input. I tried fputs() after FILE *pw = popen(sudo apt-get …”, “w”), but nothing happened. I wish u can help a bit

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
        int main()
    {
       FILE *pw = popen(“sudo apt-get …, “w”);
       fputs(“password”, pw);
    }
```

Comment: Authentication works via PAM, password entry requires TTY. You can't authenticate with stdin connected to pipe.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your code as a [mre]. Add details in which way "it is not working". Do you get an error code? Error message? Unexpected result? BTW: `sudo` may not always ask for a password, and instead of storing your password somewhere it might be better to configure `sudo` to allow certain commands without password.

Comment: @Bodo thx for your opinion, I made it a bit better

Comment: The code will probably not compile because of wrong quotes. As already written in [dimich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14772619/dimich)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867508/c-language-is-there-any-way-how-to-send-a-command-into-popen-opened-shell?noredirect=1#comment135510532_76867508), it will be more complicated. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you want to achieve with your program.

Comment: @Bodo main purpose of my code is to make automatical input. So, I will try to explain better. If you write any command which ask you to write something from keyboard, for example sudo or ssh, I’d like to input it from string instead of writing it from keyboard. For example SSH connection, which asks for password or sudo which asks for password to

Comment: @verifylion Take a look at [sshpass](https://github.com/kevinburke/sshpass/blob/master/main.c) source code.

Comment: @verifylion In general it's a bad idea to enter passwords automatically. It breaks password authentication concept. Sudo can be configured with NOPASSWD, ssh can use pubkey authentication.

Comment: @dimich Thank you bro, but I don’t want to download libraries, because I am learning c and I want to know how to make it by myself using clear C without any addictions

Comment: @verifylion Then answer to your question is: there is no way to send input to `sudo` or `ssh` opened with `popen()` in modern systems. `sshpass` is not a library, it's example how you can implement password authentication in C.

Comment: @dimich so can you advise me any other examples which can help me to implement password authentication?

Comment: @verifylion Look for PTY (pseudotty).

Comment: @dimich nothing worked, but thank you

Comment: @verifylion You should add all requested information or clarification to the question by [edit]ing it. Don't use comments for this purpose. `sudo` and `ssh` are intentionally designed to read the password from the terminal instead of `stdin`, so this might not be a suitable task for learning C. You can use `popen` to feed input to "normal" programs that read data from stdin. `popen` allows either input or output only, and it starts a shell to interpret your command string which might be problematic in some cases. For more flexibility it might be better to use `pipe`, `fork` and `exec*`.

Comment: Do what https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect does